# How to convert RGB 48-bit raw data to RGB 24-bit raw data

Tags: image, rgb, pixel

I have a scanned raw data that contains 16-bits per channel of RGB, thus, making it 48-bit per pixel data. My backend code can only handle 8-bits per channel data for RGB.

Now, I need to somehow map these 16-bits (of every channel) to 8-bits (of that channel). I tried a couple of things, but, they all resulted in randomness:

1. I tried stripping off the least significant byte from every channel.
2. I also tried a mapping technique, which seemed quite at first hunch, but later turned out to be wrong:

   I divided the 16-bit data into 256 equally placed chunks, each of which would correspond to a number in the range 0-255. This way all the 16-bit numbers will stand in 1-1 correspondence with the 8-bit numbers. But, this also failed.

Code which I used for the first try was pretty straightforward:

```
char* new_data = (char *) malloc(data.dataSize / 2);
for(int i=0, j=0; i<data.dataSize; i+=2, j++)
    new_data[j] = temp[i];
```

`temp` contains the 16-bit raw data and `new_data` will contain 8-bit raw data.

Any suggestions? May be there is some standard way to convert this, which I can't seem to find out.

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite see why your first attempt (effectively dividing by 256) would result in "randomness". It sounds like there's more to this than meets the eye. Maybe show us some code and test data/results?

Comment: Please provide sample image and code.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code which I have used.